# I want to make a button that keeps adding 5 to an id. How?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, addition

Please help. I want to add 5 to the paragraph id every single time the heal button is pressed.

```js
function heal(value3) {
  document.getElementById('defend').innerHTML = +5 defend;
}
```

```html
<p id="defend">10</p>
<input type="button" value="Heal" id="def" onclick="heal(this.value3);">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
var heal = function(value) {
 let para = document.getElementById('defend');
 para.textContent = parseInt(para.textContent) + 5;
};
```

```html
<p id="defend">10</p>
<input type="button" value="Heal" id="def" onclick="heal(this.value);">
```

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById('defend').id = + 5 defend;

Comment: OPs requirement is to add to `value` not `id`